AppwriteException Errors When Connecting to Local Docker-Hosted Appwrite Instance from React-Native App
I'm encountering issues when trying to connect to an Appwrite instance that's hosted on my local Docker setup.
When I use the endpoint "http://localhost/v1", I receive the following exception: AppwriteException: Network request failed.
When I use the endpoint "http://<ip_address>/v1", I get a different exception: AppwriteException: Network request timed out.
Interestingly, both endpoints work as expected when accessed through a web browser.
Could anyone provide some insight into why these exceptions are occurring and how I might resolve them?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
